# Google Cloud Platform - Is there possible to access the Secret Manager from GCP through Vault

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vault

We are trying to provision the F5 2NIC BIG-IP through Terraform.

I found https://github.com/memes/terraform-google-f5-bigip/tree/main/examples/standalone-2nic article to provision the F5 2-NIC through Terraform.

In this article they were using GCP Secret Manager for setting up the F5 Admin credentials while running the Terraform. We have to create the key/value pair for F5 Admin in Google Cloud Console manually before running the Terraform.

We can able to provision the F5 2NIC BIG-IP using above article but my team suggesting to avoid the creation of GCP Secret Manager manually. They are expecting some automation process for creating the GCP Secret Manager, also they are suggesting to use Vault.

Do I need to do a key/value pair in Vault and then either use that to create a Secret Manager key in Terraform for the F5 module or extend the F5 module to use the Vault pair?

Please suggest the right direction !

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I use Vault alone instead of using GCP Secret Manager